# Is there any way of checking the max memory consumption of a code that I run with the command line?

Tags: command-line, memory

The `time` command is very useful for checking how much time it takes for a piece of code that I develop to run... However, I'd like to have a way to check the memory consumption of the codes that I develop too, regardless of the language that I use. So, if it's `bash`, `python`, or `node.js`... I'd like to have a way of checking how much RAM memory I used on the code, just so I can get more aware of what I'm doing avoiding memory duplication and stuff like that. Is there any command line that I can use for checking the amount of memory that a script that I create consumes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On many Unix-like systems, yes, [GNU’s implementation of `/usr/bin/time`](http://www.gnu.org/software/time) (with the path, to avoid the similar shell built-in) will tell you how much memory a given program execution used; for example:

```
$ /usr/bin/time ls
...
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 50%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2208maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+139minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

shows that `ls` used at most 2208K of RAM.

Other tools such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) will show more information, specifically concerning heap usage:

```
$ valgrind ls
...
==10107== 
==10107== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10107==     in use at exit: 32,928 bytes in 83 blocks
==10107==   total heap usage: 506 allocs, 423 frees, 97,271 bytes allocated
==10107== 
==10107== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10107==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10107==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10107==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10107==    still reachable: 32,928 bytes in 83 blocks
==10107==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10107== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==10107== 
==10107== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10107== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: `time` is part of GNU, not part of Linux. Also it dose not seem to be installed by default on Debian. `apt install time` to install it.

Comment: Strictly speaking it’s [part of POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html), but that doesn’t specify anything beyond measuring time ;-).